# Star distribution (density of stars) as a function of distance from Galaxy centre?

Tags: galaxy-rotation-curve, galaxy-clusters

Is there any mathematical formula or empirical relation that defines the density of stars as a function of distance from the Galaxy centre in a spiral galaxy?

Comment: In a spiral galaxy, the stars tend to cluster in the arms.  There might be a function which approximates the distribution near the central black hole.

Comment: Maybe for the total mass if you had distance and angular velocity. You could probably find the avg density if you had those three things along with the emission spectrum.

Comment: When you say density of stars do you mean density that each star has, or the amount of stars per volume?

Comment: Amount of stars per unit volume

Answer (score 1):

A very crude, approximate answer would be that the density of stars decreases exponentially with distance $r$ from the center of the galaxy, and also exponentially as a function of distance $z$ above or below the plane of the disk: 
$$\rho_{\star}(r,z) = \rho_{0} \exp(-r/h) \exp(-z/z_{0})$$
where $h$ and $z_{0}$ are the radial and vertical scale lengths.

This is only approximate because it ignores the presences of "bulges" (excess concentrations of stars in the inner region of some galaxies), local variations due to bars and spiral arms, and the fact that many galaxies have deviations from the radial exponential profile at large radii (e.g., so-called "truncations", where the radial falloff changes to a steeper exponential, along with the presence of low-density, more spherical stellar "halos").

Comment: To some degree you may be right, but [it's not that simple](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.4758.pdf). Star density may follow some sort of periodic pattern, with changing $\rho_{\star}(r)$ comparing in-between and inside of spiral arms. Secondly, at least for Milky Way galaxy,- there's a discrepancy of some sort of clustering, when some arms has higher density of young stars and some arms - higher density of old stars, which raises the need of additional explanations of how such discrepancies has arrived,- Milky Way is the product of galaxy collision/accumulation in the past, etc ?

Comment: @PeterErwin may you provide a reference? Moreover, I guess that  z should be interpreted as |z| in the exponential.